# How does EXPRESSION_STMT work in Python grammar?

Tags: python, sonarqube

I am really struggling to understand how the `EXPRESSION_STMT` is seen in Python (see here to go to Python's grammar and to the correct line https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Grammar/Grammar#L41).

What does it represent in Python ?
If you have an example that would really help me :)

PS: I've been told that an analyzer using this grammar would recognize the print function through the `EXPRESSION_STMT` but I don't understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of code there are statements and there are expressions. In general, statements do not return anything but expressions do.

Statements are things such as `if`, `for`, `while` etc that do not return anything when they are finished

Expressions would be things like `3`, `True`, `1 + 7`, `"a" * 3` because they return values when they are executed

In python it is completely valid to have a line of code which is simply something like

```
1 + 2
```

this would execute, and return 3. This would be a problem for python because then there would be a 3 left on the stack. So an expression statement is basically just a wrapper for an expression which allows you to write expressions as a line of code on its own. All this means is that unlike a plain expression an expression statement pops its return value off the stack when it is finished

Hope this makes sense, if not just leave me a comment

Comment: Most importantly, it's what allows you to make a function call without, e.g,  having to save its return value in an assignment statement.